# Taking an object from array, editing one property and passing it back

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` that I want to edit. I want to check if all the members belong to class `QueueMember` (which has a property `rank`), and if it does I want it to set the value of `rank` for each object to its index in the Array.

This is what I have now which does not work. I'm wondering if it doesn't work because `*queue` is a pointer?

```
-(void)makingRankEqualtoLocationInQueue:(NSMutableArray *)queue{
    queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int queueSizeCounter = 0; queueSizeCounter <queue.count; queueSizeCounter++) {
        id obj = [queue objectAtIndex:queueSizeCounter];

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[QueueMember class]]) {
            QueueMember *member = obj;
            member.rank = queueSizeCounter;
            [queue replaceObjectAtIndex:queueSizeCounter withObject:member];
        } else {
            [queue removeObjectAtIndex:queueSizeCounter];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, im pretty new but is it necessary I still alloc/init the queue within the method in xcode5 despite declaring it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
-(void)makingRankEqualtoLocationInQueue:(NSMutableArray *)queue{
    queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

So, maybe an array arrives as a parameter (`queue` in the first line) but you then throw it away and replace it by a completely different new empty array (`queue` in the second line). So now you have an empty array, its `count` is zero, and the loop never runs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with matt, but that's not the only problem.

First, here:

```
QueueMember *member = obj;
member.rank = queueSizeCounter;
[queue replaceObjectAtIndex:queueSizeCounter withObject:member];
```

the `replaceObject` is unnecessary. `member` points to the object in the array, and if you change it, it's changed. :)

Second, are you *intending* to change the passed queue (by removing non-`QueueMember`s)? If so, maybe that side effect should be more obvious in your method naming. If not, the `removeObjectAtIndex:` is hurting you.

Finally, I don't know if this is intentional, but you'll end up with ranking that includes the non-`QueueMember` objects, perhaps something like ranks [1, 2, 5, 7, 13].